# .NET COM Interop works fine in a VB6 application on my PC, but doesn't work on the client PC - ActiveX can't create object

Tags: .net, vb6, com-interop

I have a VB.Net **Class library** project that is to be used by an ancient VB6 application. In order to allow this to work, the class library project has these 2 settings:

1. Make assembly COM-Visible
2. Register for COM interop

This allows the DLL to be used by our VB6 application. The VB6 application simply has a reference to the **.tlb** file which is created during the build. The compiled VB6 application is able to successfully instantiate the COM object and invoke its methods on the developer PC.

The problem arises when consuming the DLL from a client machine. The DLL is copied to the client machine, then `Regasm.exe myClass.dll /tlb /codebase` is executed successfully. However, once the VB6 app attempts to reference the COM object, it gets "ActiveX cannot create object". While searching, I found a recommendation to also run `regtlib` to register the .tlb file. It ran successfully, yet I still get "ActiveX cannot create object".

I want to point out that I ran a test by installing Visual Studio 2019 on a client machine and ran a build on the class library. Once I did that, the VB6 app was able to use the COM object. So, the question is, how do I do the same thing without having to build the dll with Visual Studio on the client machine?

Does anyone have any ideas as to what else I need to do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked [all the three options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5136814/11683)?

Comment: Had something similar the other day. And despite the 3 options listed in above link, it turned out that the .NET assembly was missing in the GAC. Use ```gacutil.exe -l YourAssembly``` to verify its existence. If missing add it with ```gacutil -i FullyQualifiedPathToYourAssembly```. Other than that: has your assembly other prerequesits (assmeblies etc.) that perhaps aren't present at the client's machine?

Comment: Which version of regasm.exe have you used? 64bit or 32bit? For VB6 the 32 bit version is the correct one.

Comment: I executed gacutil.exe -l MyAssembly, but no information was returned. Not sure what I was supposed to see. I also wanted to point out that I compared the registry between the developer PC and client PC.  The client PC had all the classes defined, but nowhere did I see the CodeBase registry entry which points to DLL location.

Comment: It turns out I was running the 64 bit version of RegAsm.  Once I ran the 32 bit version, it worked ok.  Thanks for all your suggestions.

Comment: Although you solved it, to answer your question, e.g. `gacutil.exe -l Microsoft.Build.Engine` returns `Microsoft.Build.Engine, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL
  Microsoft.Build.Engine, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL` on my system, i.e. your assembly should be listed there. If not, the registration failed , as you figured out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [regasm just doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136638/regasm-just-doesnt-work)

Comment: I think the OPs most recent comment confirms this is a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/a/5136814/11683